# Align center of widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I want the center of the **grey box** to be at the **black pixel** using the Align widget. (both have **same Alignment(-0.6, -0.6)**)

**Positioned.fill is needed in my case.**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-0.6, -0.6),
            child: Container(
              height: 48,
              width: 48,
              color: Colors.grey[300],
            )),
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-0.6, -0.6),
            child: Container(
              height: 1,
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            )),
      )
    ])));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that involves the **align_positioned** package, however if there is a solution that doesn't involve packages I would still be happy to know.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
        child: AlignPositioned(
            moveByChildWidth: -0.6 / 2,
            moveByChildHeight: -0.6 / 2,
            childHeight: 48,
            childWidth: 48,
            alignment: Alignment(-0.6, -0.6),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey[300],
            )),
      ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment(-0.6, -0.6),
            child: Container(
              height: 1,
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.black,
            )),
      )
    ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***How Flutter Align works***

Align widget , Alain object on his parent ... and when you set `Alignment(0,0)` this object's Center place in center of His Parent.(below image)

[image]

when you set `Alignment(1,0)` you set `x = 1` that's mean this Object's Right place on Right of his Parent.(below image)

[image]

so bigger object's MOVE slower than smalls because they way is shorter.

for Example if our screen are 100px in 100px and we have an object with 90px in 90px.
if we change Alignment from `Alignment(0,0)` to `Alignment(1,0)` how many pixel this object moving? **only 5 pixel.**   ((100 - 90)/2 = 5)

in this Example if our object size is 1px in 1px what is the answer ? **~= 50 pixel**     ((100 - 1)/2 = 49.5)

---

now what you can do ??

1. calculate the Pixel of device and .... (I don't like this way)
2. use `Composite Transform Follower` and `Composite Transform Target`

### i write an Example for `Composite Transform Follower` and `Composite Transform Target`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
// TODO: implement createState
return ssMyApp();
}
}

class ssMyApp extends State<MyApp> {
 LayerLink mylink = new LayerLink();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: <Widget>[
      Positioned.fill(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(-0.6, -0.6),
        child: CompositedTransformTarget(
        link: mylink,
        child: Container(
          height: 48,
          width: 48,
          color: Colors.grey[300],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Positioned.fill(
    child: Center(
      child: CompositedTransformFollower(
        link: mylink,
        offset: Offset(0.5, 0.5),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 24, left: 24),
          child: Container(
            height: 1,
            width: 1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
])));
}
}
```